# The distance between two convex functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a sequence $(u_t)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ so that the function $f(t)= \|u_t-u_0\|_{L^2}$ is continuous and strictly increasing and $f(0)=0$. Now, given $u'=u_0-v$ where $\int v =0$ and $\int v^2=c$ where $c$ is a constant.

Moreover, I also know that $\|u_t\|_{L^2}\leq \|u_0\|_{L^2}$ is decreasing and tends to a constant function as $t\to \infty$. (It actually goes to the average of $u_0$.)

Now, given the function $g(t) = \|u_t-u'\|_{L^2}$. I know there exists $t_0>0$ such that $g(t_0) = \min_{t>0}g(t)$. I am wondering is it possible to show the uniqueness of minimizer and also $g(t)$ is decreasing from $0$ to $t_0$ and increasing from $t_0$ to $+\infty$?